# What is the meaning of removeCallbacks(Runnable r) in Handler in Android

Tags: android, android-handler

I want to know what is the exact meaning of removeCallbacks(Runnable r) in Handler. I gone through its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and it simply says "Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue".

Now my question is if my message has already been started processing by my handler and in between if I call `removeCallbacks`, will it stop processing my half completed message? Or even if I call `removeCallbacks` the message which has already started processing by my handler (when I call `post(Runnable r)`) will be executed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Runnables should only be executed as they come out of the message queue, so if your message has already started processing it should not be effected by calling `removeCallbacks`.  It should have already been removed, so it will continue processing.

Comment: Hi Bill...One more thing..If I use async task and when running in onPostExecute and then I call asynctask.cancel(true), in that case, onPostExecute will also be canceled?

Comment: @AndroDev I don't know.  That should be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 18):

When you create a new `Handler`, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it. From that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue. `removeCallbacks` simply removes those runnables who have not yet begun processing from the queue.